# Nested routings routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I've read topics on routings over and over again but none of them could help me. So, as I am still new to Ruby, my try:

I want users to have their own projects. These projects are to have warehouses, clients and transquans. I want the URL to be like ~/user/1234/project/1/warehouse/..., so that an exclusive use is granted. This is how my routes.rb looks like:

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    resources :transquans
    resources :warehouses
    resources :clients
  end
end
```

This is how I try calling the Projects from users/show.html.erb [already tried different variations which all gave me error messages]

```
<strong>Projects</strong> <%= link_to project_path(@user) %>
```

Trying to call a given user gives me messages like

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects", :id=>#<User id: 64810937, name: "Tester 1", email....
```

That is, although I created the Projects via scaffolding and never touched the "show" action...

Trying to figure out how to fix this cost me days, while I think the solution cannot be that hard.

**EDIT:** I have now followed the first few steps in Ryan Bates' [Screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) until 4:52min. Nevertheless, when hitting 
    http://localhost:3000/users/768773789/projects

I get yet another error message that I don't understand, saying

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: projects.user_id: SELECT "projects".* FROM     "projects" WHERE ("projects".user_id = 768773789)
```

while the schema.rb looks like this

```
create_table "clients", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "codename"
  t.integer  "demand"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "projects", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Still thankful for any kind of help. This drives me mad.

Comment: Run command `rake routes` to see your current routes.

Comment: I've added the Ruby on Rails tag under the assumption that this is the web framework you are using. (Ruby is a programming language; Rails is a Web Framework using it.) If this is not correct, please correct the tags and clarify your question.

Comment: You need to post your `rake routes`

Answer (score 0):

The `project_path` helper method only works if you have a 'top level' project, with routes like `GET /project/id`. It doesn't fail completely, because an entity `Project` does exist. It only tells you that no route matches, which is misleading in cases such as this one.

You need the `user_projects_path` helper method, similar to the `magazine_ads_url` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: I still get `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects"}`. I am trying to match via `match 'users/:id/projects', :to => 'users_projects#index'`. May this cause the mistake as well?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the output of `rake routes`, it should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see any problems with the output. I have uploaded an image of it on http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45905590/rakeroutes.png

Comment: it tells you that to see all projects for a user, you should use `user_projects_path(user)`, and to see a particular project of a user, `user_project_path(project)`